# Hybrid Pow/Pos Consensus Node Blocks are not being finalized?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-recipes, pos

i am following this tutorial https://substrate.recipes/hybrid-consensus.html trying to make a Hybrid pow/pos based consensus node i also watched Joshy Orndorff demonstration on  hybrid consensus with Proof of Work authoring and Proof of Stake finality. https://youtu.be/6omrrY11HEg. but i  am facing some issue blocks are not getting finalized?[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can follow https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/consensus-models/create-a-hybrid-node/ for the same. The one that you were using was old one.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham